# Unit Testing with expected errors

Tags: unit-testing

For my [ColorJizz](http://code.google.com/p/colorjizz) library, I'm *expecting* slight errors when you do multiple conversions between different color formats. The errors are all very small (i.e. 0.0001 out).

What do you think I should do about these?

I feel like there are 2 real options:

1. Leave them as they are, with almost 30% of tests failing
2. Put some kind of 'error range' in my unit tests and pass them if they're within that range. But how do I judge what level or error I should have?

Here's an example of the kind of failures I'm getting:

http://www.mikeefranklin.co.uk/tests/test/

What would be the best solution?

Comment: I hope you are aware of the colloquial usage of the second half of your libraries name.  If you are and you still named it that, then you must have .. um .. err .. well .. you know what I mean.

Comment: Ah yes, very aware. It's just a bit of fun really :) I asked for name suggestions and that one seemed the most.... creative. No doubt it'll make a few people avoid it, but that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error range is the standard approach for floating point "equality" tests.

[NUnit uses "within"](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5.5):

> ```
> Assert.That( 2.1 + 1.2, Is.EqualTo( 3.3 ).Within( .0005 );
> ```

[Ruby's test/unit uses `assert_in_delta`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#M004525):

> ```
> assert_in_delta 0.05, (50000.0 / 10**6), 0.00001
> ```

And most other test frameworks have something similar.  Apparently qunit is one that does *not* have something similar, but it would be easy enough to modify [the source](http://github.com/jquery/qunit/raw/master/qunit/qunit.js) to include one of your design.

As for the actual delta to use, it depends on your application.  I would think that 0.01 would be actually pretty restrictive for humans to visually identify color differences, but it would be a fairly lax requirement mathematically.

Comment: About [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) not having floating point comparison, you can use [`closeEnough` plugin/addon](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/tree/v1.11.0/addons/close-enough), as suggested here: https://github.com/jquery/qunit/issues/429

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using floating point values, for which [rounding errors are a fact of life](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). I recommend applying an error margin for comparison checks in your unit tests.

Leaving even some of your unit tests failing is not a realistic option - **unit tests should pass 100% under normal circumstances**. If you let some of them fail regularly, you won't easily notice when there is a new failure, signifying a real bug in your code.

Comment: Is there any preferred approach to automatically adapting returned results to become future expected results?  On many implementations, if a formula which doesn't use transcendental functions doesn't change, the output shouldn't either.  A tiny change in output will often not indicate a bug, but may suggest that the way something is being computed has changed and should be investigated.

Comment: @supercat, I don't know of any. This should always be decided on a case by case basis - a difference which is acceptable in one case may be an error in another. Which is which? should always be decided by a human.

Answer (score 0):

[**Gallio/MbUnit**](http://gallio.org) has a dedicated assertion for that specific test case ([`Assert.AreApproximatelyEqual`](http://gallio.org/api/html/M_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreApproximatelyEqual__2.htm))

```
double a = 5;
double b = 4.999;
Assert.AreApproximatelyEqual(a, b, 0.001); // Pass!
```